# Get all entries with linked entry in entries field

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi, query

I have a channel called 'projects'. 
This channel has two `entries fields`:

- relatedThemes
- relatedAreas

What I want to do is perform a search query which filters all projects where the `relatedThemes` field has an entry with a certain `id`.

I figured out how to search custom fields. Here's an example of a filter with a plain text field with a handle `test`.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section: 'projects'
}).search('test:testValue') %}
```

This returns all project entries where the `test` field has the `testValue` value, as expected.

But I can't seem to make this work with an entries field. I thought I could do something like this

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
  section: 'projects'
}).search('entriesfield.id:relatedThemesID') %}
```

But this does not work.

Another important thing is that I ***can't actually use template logic***, because the query is to be used in the [element api](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) (for Craft 2).

I'm not a backend dev, so I test the `criteria` array in templates first and then convert it to php.

So the correct criteria array for the test text field would be

```
'criteria' => [
  'section' => 'projects',
  'test' => 'testValue'
],
```

Comment: If Robin Schambach's answer was the one that helped you fix this consider checking this answer as the correct one. It helps others on here to find answers faster.

Comment: Done @xaddict .
Pretty new to stackexchange, so thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs about [relations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/relations.html#the-relatedTo-param)?

```
'criteria' => [
    'section' => 'projects', 
    'test' => 'testValue' 
    'relatedTo' => id
]
```

Just replace `id` with the ID of your element

If you want to filter a specific field you have to include it as an array

```
'relatedTo' => [
    'sourceElement' => id,
    'field' => 'fieldHandle'
]
```

Comment: Indeed, `relatedTo` was the missing key! Thanks a lot.